# Are point clouds faster to render than triangle meshes? What are the advantages of using one over the other?

Tags: computational-geometry, graphics

I searched online but I couldn't find any comparison between rendering a point cloud and rendering a triangle mesh.

Comment: Of course it's faster to draw points without creating a surface from these points, and then rendering the surface. It's so obvious that I think I don't get your question

Comment: Then why in games don't they use ultra dense point clouds for the scenery?

Comment: @Christian Because then you're again *increasing* the number of points (and would have to immensely so for them to be practically "watertight"), which of course makes everything different. This brings us to the problem that this question really is a little too broad and it depends on a *ton* of things (as does the general question about pros/cons).